# Change Background Image website but Protect the body in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to make a background like this except using an image instead of the blue background: http://gakeyclub.org/

Notice that resizing the window of the browser does not disturb the background. What do I need for this?

Comment: your example simply uses a colored background, what do you mean by "disturb"?

Comment: When I have a picture as the background, and when I resize the window of my browser wider, the page automatically moves to the center of the window while the picture in the background is fixed to the left of the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, what you are asking is to have your background center on your page. To do so use `background-position` this will tell the browser where to position the background according to its container.

```
background-position:50% 50%;
```

You might like to add some other background attributes such as `background-repeat:no-repeat` to make sure the picture does not repeat on huge resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

this is how your css should be looking for a fixed image as background:

```
body
{ 
background-image:url('image.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use an image. It will just increase the size of the page. Use this code:-

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #002f5f;
```